# Javascript function on submit button - Wait for it to complete

Tags: javascript

I want to trigger a function when the submit button is pressed on the form and wait for the javascript function to complete, then continue the form submission. I dont want the form to submit before the javascript function has completed.**

This is what I have at the moment:
http://jsfiddle.net/njDvn/68/

```
function autosuggest() {
var input = document.getElementById('location');
    var options = {
    types: [],
    };
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
}

<!-- Get lat / long -->      
function getLatLng() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = document.getElementById('location').value;
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latLng = results[0].geometry.location;
            $('#lat').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
            $('#lng').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}

<!-- Load it --> 
window.onload = autosuggest;
```

Comment: From my research I have found this is what I might need but I dont really understand its use: document.getElementById('disable-submit').submit();

Comment: I am not entirely sure where you're getting stuck, but the general procedure would be listening to the form's submit event, cancelling it, doing whatever async action you wish to do and then submitting what you want callback, either using the form itself or by using AJAX.

Comment: Yes that is what I dont know how to do, trigger the function on button click and run submit when it is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can intercept the form submission, abort it and send the geocoding request to Google.

When the server responds, you can re-submit the form from the callback (or display an error in case of failure).

Store the state of the request somewhere (for the sake of simplicity, I'm using a global variable in my example). In this case, it's just a flag that indicates whether or not the geocoding request was completed successfully (so that now, when the form is submitted and the listener is re-triggered, it will know not to re-send the geocoding request).

http://jsfiddle.net/njDvn/75/

Feel free to remove the console logging.

You may also want to make the lat/long fields hidden.

```
var GeoCoded = {done: false}; // this holds the status of the geo-coding request

$(document).ready(function(){
    autosuggest(); // place your auto-suggest (now called autocomplete) box

    $('#myform').on('submit',function(e){

        if(GeoCoded.done)
            return true;

        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('submit stopped');
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = document.getElementById('location').value;

        // disable the submit button
        $('#myform input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled',true);

        // send the request
        geocoder.geocode({
            'address': address
        },
        function (results, status) {
            // update the status on success
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var latLng = results[0].geometry.location;
                $('#lat').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                $('#lng').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                // if you only want to submit in the event of successful 
                // geocoding, you can only trigger submission here.
                GeoCoded.done = true; // this will prevent an infinite loop
                $('#myform').submit();
            } else { // failure
                console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                //enable the submit button
                $('#myform input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled',false);
            }


        });        

    });   

});
```

Comment: I added this code to my fiddle but couldnt get it working: http://jsfiddle.net/njDvn/76/

Comment: I have added the fiddler link to my answer.

Comment: Hi. why doesn't the `$('#myform').submit();` re trigger the `$('#myform').on('submit',function(e){ `  ? @MasterAM Surly it would be a continuous loop that keeps calling its self?

Comment: Is it because of scope?

Comment: It is because of the flag that I set when the callback ran successfully (`GeoCoded.done = true;`). There are other ways to submit the data to the server, such as using AJAX. I updated the answer to make it more descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to prevent the form to be submitted, add a `return false` at the end of `getLatLng()` function.

Then when the geocoding is done, submit the form manually with `document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit()`

Here's an updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/njDvn/70/

Answer (score 0):

```
myFunction = new function(callback) {
    $.ajax({...}).done(callback());
}

myFunction(new function() {
    getLatLng();
});
```

Here you need to call `myFunction` onSubmit event.

Answer (score 0):

As MasterAM has stated, all you need do is the following:

```
/// I've included the following function to allow you to bind events in a 
/// better way than using the .onevent = function(){} method.
var addEvent = (function(){
  if ( window.addEventListener ) {
    return function(elm, eventName, listener, useCapture){
      return elm.addEventListener(eventName,listener,useCapture||false);
    };
  }
  else if ( window.attachEvent ) {
    return function(elm, eventName, listener){
      return elm.attachEvent('on'+eventName,listener);
    };
  }
})();

/// add another window.onload listener
addEvent(window,'load',function(){
  /// find the form, obviously should use whatever id you have on your form
  var form = document.getElementById('my_form');
      form.preventSubmit = true;
  /// add our onsubmit handler
  addEvent(form,'submit',function(e){
    /// only stop the form if we haven't already
    if ( form.preventSubmit ) {
      /// place/call whatever code you need to fire before submit here.
      alert('submit was blocked!');
      /// after that code is complete you can use the following
      form.preventSubmit = false;
      form.submit();
      /// return false prevents the submit from happening
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```